# acceptable columns names in sql table

Tags: sql

I am creating a table from a CSV file and was wondering where would I find a doc that will tell me what columns names are acceptable? I know you cant have "/" or spaces in the columns names.

What is the fastest way to clean a csv and turn it into a sql table?

Comment: Each RDBMS has its own reserved words (beyond the standard SQL ones) and its own rules for what characters may be in a column name. In addition, there may be ways to escape certain characters so that they will work even if they don't work on the surface. Short version: check the documentation for the database product you're using (you haven't specified here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of recommendations:

- Uvoid special characters (except for underscore)
- Use CamelCase if you don't want to use unserscore
- Set a naming convention for your company that you will enforce

Here are some useful articles:

[General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx)

[SQL Server Standards](http://www.isbe.state.il.us/ILDS/pdf/SQL_server_standards.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

A fast way would be to create the database and table in sql, or the platform you are using.  Then create each column with type/restrictions in the order the CSV file is in.  Then upload the CSV file.